# Can I plug functions created with lambda x on a list? (python)

Tags: python, list, function, numpy, lambda

I need to build a polynomial function like a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*x^2 ... I am trying to do the whole interpolation process.
I have this:

```
def Create_F(Numero, Array):
    Y = lambda x: x
    Lista = list(Array)
    F_x = [] 
    for i in range(Numero):
      G_x = lambda x: eval(Lista[i]*Y^i)
      F_x.append(G_x)
    return F_x
```

And if I use this, I do not get nothing that help:

```
Number = 2
ma = np.array([[1, 1],
               [1, 2]])
ly = np.array([8, -3])

idk = Create_F(Number, ly)
print(idk)
```

I don't know how to evaluate, for example 1. If I can do this in a better way it would be very helpful, the complete code is:

```
import numpy as np

def Matrix_F(Num, Lx):
    Vec = np.zeros((Num, Num), dtype = float)
    Vec.T[1] = Lx
    ex = 0
    for i in range(Num):
        for j in range(Num):
            Vec[j][i]=Lx[j]**ex
        ex += 1
    return Vec

def Cramer_F(Ma, Ly):
    Lc, Det = np.array(Ly), np.linalg.det(Ma)
    col = len(Lc)
    Values = np.zeros(col)
    for i in range(col):
        org = Ma.copy()
        org.T[i]=Lc
        Di=np.linalg.det(org)
        Values[i] = Di/Det
    error = np.linalg.norm(np.dot(Ma, Values)-Lc)
    return Values, error
    

def Create_F(Numero, Array):
    Y = lambda x: x
    Lista = list(Array)
    F_x = [] 
    for i in range(Numero):
      G_x = lambda x: eval(Lista[i]*Y^i)
      F_x.append(G_x)
    return F_x


val = int(input('Ingrese la cantidad de valores de X y Y que posee: '))
x_val = []
y_val = []

print('Ingrese %s valores de cada variable:' %(val))

n = 1
for i in range(val):
    x = float(input('%s° Valor de x: '%(n)))
    y = float(input('%s° Valor de y: '%(n)))
    x_val.append(x)
    y_val.append(y)
    n += 1

#Matriz del sistema:
As = Matrix_F(val, x_val)

#Valores de "a_n" y error
a_val, er = Cramer_F(As, y_val)

n=0
print()
for i in a_val:
    print('a_%s = %.6f' %(n, i))
    n += 1
```

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: The statement `eval(Lista[i]*Y^i)` is strange. First, you are muliplying your list item by a lambda function. This has no meaning. Secondly you are doing `eval` on the result. But eval is used for evaluating source code, typically a string.  Rewrite your expression one step at a time and very that everything works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I hit your mind, you want to create a polynomial representation as lambda function. so let me suggest alternative function:

```
import numpy as np
def alternative_create_F(coeffs):
    Y = lambda x: sum([item*(x**iter) for iter, item in enumerate(coeffs)])
    return Y

coeffs = np.array([8, -3, 4]) # first is the free coeff second is x coeff and so on

idk = alternative_create_F(coeffs)
print(idk(3))
print(idk(6))
```

pay attention that `number` variable is irrelevant, because you can extract it from the `len(coeffs)`.

Now the lambda function holds the representation of the polynomial -

```
coeffs[0] + coeffs[1]*x + coeffs[2]*x^2
```

to invoke the lambda function, call it as a function with the wanted x value.
the output recieved from my examples:

```
35 ===> 8+(-3)*3+4*3^2 = 8-9+36 = 35 
134 ===> 8+(-3)*6+4*6^2 = 8-18+144 = 134
```

Hope you find it useful